# Je n'ai jamais entendu utiliser la tournure « à ce à quoi » mais est-elle juste? Y a-t-il d’autre manières de l’exprimer?

Tags: formulation

Je parle uniquement des phrase complexes qui se divisent en deux avec « ce que » au milieu. Mais si j'ai bien compris la logique, on utilise « ce à quoi » au lieu de « ce que » quand la partie ultime exige un COI.

> Je ne pense pas que ce soit **ce à quoi** on s'attendait [s'attendre à]

Mais si la première partie [penser à] en exige aussi, dirait-on « à ce à quoi »?

> Je pense actuellement **à ce à quoi** les autres s'attendaient [s'attendre à]

Cependant, même dans [les traducteurs en ligne](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/%C3%A0+ce+%C3%A0+quoi.html), je n'en trouve aucun exemple

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a aucun problème, malgré le rapprochement pas très euphonique des deux a, cette combinaison  est bien  utilisée, et en voici de nombreux exemples: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+ce+%C3%A0+quoi+&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3), [à ce à quoi](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A0%20ce%20%C3%A0%20quoi%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

[image]

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Est_ce_le_livre_en_question/D_frDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A0+ce+%C3%A0+quoi%22&pg=PT42&printsec=frontcover)) Avez-vous la capacité de penser à ce à quoi vous ne pensez pas ? Avez-vous la capacité de penser à ce à quoi je vous invite à penser ?

Comment: Une euphonie peut difficilement être gênante. Tu veux probablement dire le manque d'euphonie.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est ça, je situe mal le sens, je corrige. Merci.